# can provider-hosted app deployed outside the domain when using s2s

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-addin, domain, provider-hosted-app, s2s

I'm creating a SharePoint provider-hosted app using visual studio 2013 in a machine and connecting to SharePoint 2013 on another machine.

Visual studio is not in the same domain as SharePoint domain. I'm using S2S to establish trust between the app and SharePoint.

After creating this whole setup the app doesn't work while debugging on the Visual studio machine. It only work when it's hosted inside the SharePoint domain.

Does the provider hosted app have to be hosted on the same domain? or I missed some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Provider hosted app may be any domain (it is their characteristic), but the automatic deploy directly from Visual Studio do not go 
Try rebuild and deploy app to SP manualy, then use remote debugging for debugging app.

It is better to have Visual Studio on the development server.